# Adjust Prices by Product Category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpallimport

I have a clients website that uses WP All Import Pro to import products into WooCommerce from an external website via an XML Link.
All of this works well and we have adjusted the price using the WOOCOMMERCE ADD-ON as shown here
[image: Price Ajust]

What we would like to achieve is to adjust the price for different WooCommerce categories within the WP All Import Pro feed settings.

Many thanks

Comment: What are the "WP All Import Pro feed settings"?

Comment: Hi @montrealist You can view the settings on this screen grab: https://jatsmobiles.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Screenshot_2020-10-26-Manage-Imports-%E2%80%B9-Jet-Fast-Logistics-%E2%80%94-WordPress1.png